# Proving that $\pi_q(T(S^m)\setminus f^{-1}(A))\cong \pi_q(S^m\setminus A)$ for $q\ge 1$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, higher-homotopy-groups

Consider the tangent fiber bundle $(T(S^m), f, S^m)$ and the finite set $A\subseteq S^m$. Here $f:T(S^m)\to S^m, f(x, v)=x$ just to have everything defined.

I am first asked to prove that the restriction and co-restriction $T(S^m)\setminus f^{-1}(A)\stackrel{g}{\longmapsto}S^m\setminus A$, $(x, v)\mapsto x$ is a locally trivial fibration with fiber $\mathbb{R}^m$. This was easy because I already know that $f$ is a locally trivial fibration and we just write the definition.

Then the following question asks me to show that $\pi_q(T(S^m)\setminus f^{-1}(A))\cong \pi_q(S^m\setminus A)$ for $q\ge 1$. I don't really know how to do this. Of course, I believe that this has something to do with the fact that $g$ is a locally trivial fibration, but I don't know any result about this. I tried to write the exact sequence associated with this fibration but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: If $A$ consists of a single point, can you answer the question?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese if $A$ consists of a single point, then $f^{-1}(A)$ is just the tangent space at that point, but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: What is $S^n\setminus A$ in this case and what do you know about its tangent bundle?

Comment: Big hint: think of the stereographic projections in the case of $S^2$

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Ah, I see what you are hinting at. Well, in this case $S^n \setminus A$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ via the stereographic projection and the tangent bundle is trivial, but on the left side we have $T(S^m)$, not $T(S^m\setminus A)$, how should I continue?

Comment: @Chris Okay, so with the stereographic projection we have that if $A$ has $k$ elements then $S^m\setminus A$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m \setminus \{k-1 \text{ points}\}$, but how does this help?

Comment: Well, per my first hint $TS^2/\smallsetminus f^{-1}((1,0,0))$, is the tangent bundle minus the tangent space at the north pole. The pushforward of the stereographic projection chart then gives you an isomorphism of vector bundles $TS^2\smallsetminus f^{-1}((1,0,0))\rightarrow T\mathbb R^2\cong \mathbb{R}^4$

Comment: @Chris so basically that isomorphism of fundamental groups I have to prove is just a consequence of the fact that those two spaces are in fact homeomorphic if I am reading what you wrote correctly?

Comment: (In my last comment I used $n$ when I should have used $m$. I will use $m$ now where I used $n$ before). Actually $S^m\setminus A$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$ and the left hand side isn't $TS^m$ but $TS^m\setminus f^{-1}(A)$ which you can show is the tangent bundle of $S^m\setminus A$ (more generally, if $U \subset M$ is an open subset of a smooth manifold $M$, then $TU \cong TM|_U$).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez sorry for the late reply. I must admit that I am not that experienced with algebraic topology or exact sequences. I realize now that one in every three of the groups involved is zero since the fiber is $\mathbb{R}^m$, but how exactly should I continue afterward?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez wow, thanks for pointing this out. I wrote now that sequence again and I realize that the conclusion was indeed trivial. Previously I basically looked at the wrong part of the exact sequence, so silly of me.